# Is my controlling idea for my poem analysis accurate?

Tags: poetry, kahlil-gibran

This is my current controlling idea of my essay on the poem "On Pleasure":

> "The speaker challenges the idea of pleasure in the minds of the
> audience, and argues that pleasure is an unavoidable part of life;
> only by accepting this, and giving and receiving pleasure, can one
> enjoy life to the fullest."

The poem is pretty difficult to understand for me, so I was wondering if it accurately illustrates the point the author is trying to make, and covers the entire poem. Also, is it more of a summary, or does it actually goes into the deeper meaning behind the poem?

Here is the poem, quoted from [Kahlil Gibran on Pleasure](http://www.katsandogz.com/gibran/onpleasure.php):

> Pleasure is a freedom-song, But it is not freedom. It is the
> blossoming of your desires, But it is not their fruit. It is a depth
> calling unto a height, But it is not the deep nor the high. It is the
> caged taking wing, But it is not space encompassed. Ay, in very truth,
> pleasure is a freedomsong. And I fain would have you sing it with
> fullness of heart; yet I would not have you lose your hearts in the
> singing.
>
> Some of your youth seek pleasure as if it were all, and they are
> judged and rebuked. I would not judge nor rebuke them. I would have
> them seek. For they shall find pleasure, but not her alone; Seven are
> her sisters, and the least of them is more beautiful than pleasure.
> Have you not heard of the man who was digging in the earth for roots
> and found a treasure?
>
> And some of your elders remember pleasures with regret like wrongs
> committed in drunkenness. But regret is the beclouding of the mind and
> not its chastisement. They should remember their pleasures with
> gratitude, as they would the harvest of a summer. Yet if it comforts
> them to regret, let them be comforted.
>
> And there are among you those who are neither young to seek nor old to
> remember; And in their fear of seeking and remembering they shun all
> pleasures, lest they neglect the spirit or offend against it. But even
> in their foregoing is their pleasure. And thus they too find a
> treasure though they dig for roots with quivering hands. But tell me,
> who is he that can offend the spirit? Shall the nightingale offend the
> stillness of the night, or the firefly the stars? And shall your flame
> or your smoke burden the wind? Think you the spirit is a still pool
> which you can trouble with a staff?
>
> Oftentimes in denying yourself pleasure you do but store the desire in
> the recesses of your being. Who knows but that which seems omitted
> today, waits for tomorrow? Even your body knows its heritage and its
> rightful need and will not be deceived. And your body is the harp of
> your soul, And it is yours to bring forth sweet music from it or
> confused sounds.
>
> And now you ask in your heart, "How shall we distinguish that which is
> good in pleasure from that which is not good?" Go to your fields and
> your gardens, and you shall learn that it is the pleasure of the bee
> to gather honey of the flower, But it is also the pleasure of the
> flower to yield its honey to the bee. For to the bee a flower is a
> fountain of life, And to the flower a bee is a messenger of love, And
> to both, bee and flower, the giving and the receiving of pleasure is a
> need and an ecstasy.
>
> People of Orphalese, be in your pleasures like the flowers and the
> bees.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: +1, interesting question. However, is it necessary to include the entire text of the poem in your post? You could simply link to the page where the full poem can be read. It may not matter for a poem as old as this one, but with more recent poems there might (?? IANAL) be some issues about copyright.